# Can't persist object to DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to persist an object to the DB, where the id of the object is auto generated. The issue is that for some reason the ID remains null(I also tried hardcoding a id in the constructor, but it is still seen as null). I tested inserting an object to the DB running a sql query and I can see the entry in the table.The model class is:`

```
package com.dealFinder.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "deals")
public class DealModel { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Title is mandatory")
    private String title;
    @NotBlank(message = "Url is mandatory")
    private String url;
    private float price;

    public DealModel(String title, String url, float price){
//        this.id = 1;
        this.title=title;
        this.url = url;
        this.price= price;
    }

    public DealModel(){}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false)
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

I create the object with `

```
model = new DealModel(title, productUrl, price);
```

`where title, productUrl and price are not null, and I persist it to the DB with`

```
dealsRepository.save(dealModel);
```

`where the dealRepository class is`

```
@Repository
public interface DealsRepository extends JpaRepository<DealModel, Integer> {
}
```

` Not sure what wrong change I made recently, as it was working fine previously.

I am trying to persist the delModel object to the DB. Running a manual query to insert a dealModel entry to the table works fine

Comment: Why do you have the mapping on the attribute and the getter? You must choose one

Comment: `int` is a primitive and defaults to `0`.. Make it in `Integer` instead.

Comment: Show the class wich contains  'dealsRepository.save(dealModel);'. 
Have you inject your dependency ?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I tried keeping the mapping just on the attribute and just on the getter, but it still doesn't work. The ID will always be null
M.Deinum I made the Id type Integer, but it still not helps
HamzaKhadhri save method is a method from CrudRepository

Comment: I've created an example project with your code and everything works fine. Check it out https://github.com/simasch-scratches/so-74530613

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I tried running the code from your branch but I can't see anything persisted to the DB

Comment: The app uses a in-memory database H2. After the application finished the data is lost

Comment: @SimonMartinelli what would I have to add to be able to persist to a postgres DB? I was able to persist entries to the DB with a similar version of code I initially mentioned, but I copied the code to another laptop and made some changes and now it doesn't work and I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: You will have to add the database driver, start a database and configure the URL, username and password. https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-postgresql/